# Facebook connector fail gracefully

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

I'm using the Javascript connector from facebook and I have implemented things as per their instructions and all is well, until facebook is blocked by a corporate policy. Then you get a failure doing this:

```
ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
```

I added try/catch around it and it still fails.

I have also tried just adding the `<script id=...` No good.

I have tried it a different way and I can see the problem, I wrote this function :

```
jQuery.cachedFacebookScript = function(url, options) {

    // Allow user to set any option except for dataType, cache, and url
    // Use $.ajax() since it is more flexible than $.getScript
    // Return the jqXHR object so we can chain callbacks
    return jQuery.ajax({
        dataType : "script",
        //cache : true,
        url : url, 
        error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, exception) {
            logger("Ajax failure: " + exception);
        }});
};
```

and then added

```
$.cachedFacebookScript('//connect.facebook.net/en_UK/all.js')
    .done(function() {console.log("Done");})
    .error(function() {console.log("Error");})
;
```

None of the callbacks get called so I can't trap the error.

If I remove the `dataType : "script",` line, both of the error callbacks get called.

So it smells like a JQuery bug to me, so one way round might be to eval() the javascript that I get back in the success callback... but I don't get that far with the above, when I do have access to facebook I get this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://connect.facebook.net/en_UK/all.js. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:9080' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Which from other question on here seems to be a server thing... so how does $.getScript() get the javascript? the doco says its a wrapper round $.ajax, so I wrote a new wrapper:

```
jQuery.myGetScript = function(url, success, error) {
    $.ajax({
          url: url,
          success: function(response) {
              eval(response);
              success();
          },
          error: function (response) {
              error();
          }
        });
}
```

I get the same Origin error.

The JQuery documentation says that as of JQuery 1.5 you can add a fail()... no you can't this does not work:

```
jQuery.myGetScript = function(url, success, error) {
    logger("Calling getScript()");
    ret = $.getScript(url)
        .done(function( script, textStatus ) {
            console.log("Successfully loaded script");
            success();
        })
        .fail(function( jqxhr, settings, exception ) {
            console.log("Failed to load script");
            error();
        });
};
```

Is there a way to make this fail gracefully, or at least throw something I can trap and handle/ignore?